# Website Scroll When All Contents Are loaded

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, background-image

Is there some code that makes scrolling between containers possible before all content loads like it usually does? In my website scroll is stuck and after 2 minutes when the website finished loading it scrolls.

I think there should be a code to scroll between different background images or containers. Do you have an idea?

Comment: Sorry but what exactly do you mean by scrolling between containers? Would be great if you could explain that part. Also if you're site really does take 2 minutes to fully load you should really consider fixing this instead of making the waiting time less boring. No one will wait 2 minutes for a website to fully load.

Comment: I updated the tags. Java and javascript aren't the same thing and it is safe to assume you are looking for javascript.

Comment: I would recommend fixing your 2 minute load time. There are solutions for this depending on the cause.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.